# OpenCV : Python equivalent of `setTo` in C++

Tags: python, c++, opencv, image-processing

What is the python equivalent of [Mat::setTo](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.10/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-setto) in C++ ?

What I'm trying to do is to set value by mask:

```
Mat img;
...
img.setTo(0, mask);
```

**Update:**

Here is possible solution:

```
#set by mask area to zero
img= np.random.rand(200, 200, 3) * 255
img= img.astype(np.uint8)
mask = np.zeros((200, 200), np.uint8)
mask[10:100, 60:140] = 255
inv_mask= cv2.bitwise_not(mask)
n_channels= img.shape[2]
for i in range(0,n_channels):
    img[..., i]= img[..., i] * (inv_mask/255)

#to set arbitary value
img= np.random.rand(200, 200, 3) * 255
img= img.astype(np.uint8)
mask= np.zeros((200,200), np.uint8)
mask[10:100, 60:140]= 255
mask_bool= np.where(mask > 0)
value= 120
img[mask_bool]= value
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply use `img[mask > 0] = 0` which is the python equivalent of `img.setTo(0, mask);`

Answer (score 3):

opencv in python uses numpy as backend (more specifically numpy.ndarray) for images. This means you can do the following:

```
import numpy
img = numpy.zeros((256, 256, 3))  # This initializes a color image as an array full of zeros
```

Then if i wish to set the third channel as 1 all I have to do is:

```
img[:, :, 2:3] = 1
```

Therefore if Mask has the same dimensions as my third channel i can use it to set the third channel:

```
img[:, :, 2:3] = mask
```

edited after comment: in case you simply wish to set pixels of image to zeros using a mask a simple `image * mask` should suffice. make sure mask has same number of dimensions as image.

edit #2: Yeah that might work, but if the shape of your mask is the only issue, i would use `mask[:, :, numpy.newaxis]` to add a dimension and then multiply with image.

btw `numpy.newaxis` is same as using `mask[:,:,None]`.

Comment: It will rewrite whole plane with mask but I need to set specific pixels of image to zero by mask.

Comment: Edited original answer.

Comment: img is (256, 256, 3) and mask is usually (256, 256) so `image * mask` will not work. See my update for valid answer.

Comment: Why not just add an axis?

Comment: @mrgloom You have to set a mask (binary image) having all the pixels of the original image that you want to set to a particular color. Then perform **bitwise-AND**  `cv2.bitwise_and()`. You would have only the pixels of the original image that you want to change