# Most efficient way to mask an opencv bgr with a boolean array

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have an image loaded with opencv with `img.shape = (208, 117, 3)`. I also have a boolean numpy array with `mask.shape = (208, 117)`. How to I make all pixels in the `img` `(0,0,0)` wherever the `mask` has False, otherwise leave the pixels as they are?

Comment: Just let broadcasting take care of the shapes and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38193958/how-to-properly-mask-a-numpy-2d-array

Comment: Hmm, that didn't solve it for me. That solution has a different sized output. I want the output img to be the same size. Just all pixels where my mask had false should go to zero.

Comment: Rough pseudocode: `a[mask] = (0, 0, 0)` is roughly what you want. The mask only gives you access to the relevant pixels, you still need to set them to something

Comment: @sshashank124 your answers inspired me. See my answer below. Thank you.

Comment: The image is a numpy array, right? Have you read the NumPy docs?

Comment: Not all of them. But yes, I do frequently visit the docs.

Comment: in c++ there is an opencv .setTo function which accepts a mask (which you would have to invert first). Maybe that function exists in python, too?

Comment: @Micka looks like not, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829511/opencv-python-equivalent-of-setto-in-c/41850675 
But still I think the method in the answer is good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer is

`img[~mask,:] = [0,0,0]`

That `,:` takes care of the other dimension so you don't get mismatch issues.